# react-native - javascript sort

Tags: javascript, react-native, performance

I'm using the code below to deduplicate and sort an array containing about 2000 entries:

```js
sortedData = [...new Set(citiesData.flatMap(item => item.cities))].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en'))
```

On Android it works very slowly (30 seconds to get the result) and on iOS it returns very quickly. Why does that discrepancy exist?

Comment: My only advice is: Do not ever get 2000 items from a single API call, this will most likely cause performance issues (either on Android or on IOS), you have to do some sort of pagination and get a chunk of data whenever the user scroll/click a button. Remember that not all users have a strong and stable network connection.

Answer (score 0):

Is your benchmark based on release builds tested on actual devices, or did you just try your code in the emulators for the respective platforms?

If your benchmark refers to the emulators, then it's highly likely that the difference you're seeing is attributable to the Android emulator being way less performant. The last time I wrote code on RN (a while ago admittedly), I developed on the iOS emulator exclusively, because the Android one was basically unusable. The performance difference in production was not that stark however.

EDIT: the culprit is `localeCompare`, which is apparently much slower on Android, as reported [here](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/867).

As already stated in the cited source, changing your code to

```
const collator = new Intl.Collator('en');
sortedData = [...new Set(citiesData.flatMap(item => item.cities))].sort((a, b) => collator.compare(a, b))
```

should result in a consistent improvement.

Comment: I check on physical devices, in the testing phase on a connected cable

Comment: Then it might very well be `localeCompare` https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/867

Comment: thanks, this link helped me a lot, I went from 30 seconds to 6 seconds. I think that the already released version should be much better.